# GPS quick settings tile

Tags: gps, 9.0-pie, quick-settings

I have a bootleggers [ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e-2015/orig-development/rom-bootleggers-rom-moto-e-2015-lte-t3725351) (Android 9 pie) installed on a Motorola Moto E 2015 phone. Can I add a quick settings tile that would toggle the GPS (location) on and off?

I know there is already a "location" tile, built in the rom, that can switch between different location modes (high accuracy, etc.), but I only want to toggle the GPS on and off, not to change the modes.
Also, I already solved this by using Tasker and [QuickTask](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.balda.quicktask) app to create a custom tile. And it works, but sometimes it takes some time for it to respond (which is understandable having in mind my phone's specs and the fact that now two additional apps are used to control the tile). I don't know if the delay is caused by QuickTask, by Tasker or by both, and it also depends on how many apps are open at the time that I use the tile.

So, maybe there is a more reliable and quicker solution.

Comment: Just saying, the "location" tile works alright on my devices, though they all have much better HW than your device...

Comment: Are you using a custom rom?

Comment: LineageOS on all my devices.

Comment: And the location tile simply toggles the location between on and off? not switching between "high accuracy", "battery saving" and "sensors only" location modes?

Comment: Advanced location tile was only added recently in LOS, and even then tapping the icon part of the tile would still instantly toggle on/off GPS. This extra question does confuse me a bit though, are you just unsatisfied with the tri-mode behaviour and want to have a tile that just toggles on/off, or does the tile seem to work but GPS isn't actually turned on immediately (as your original question emphasized "delay")?

Comment: Yep, I just want a tile that turns GPS on/off. I don't want to switch between different modes and I think switching to high accuracy brings a confirmation dialog where I should let google access more of my personal data, to which I disagree and then I think the original location tile of Bootleggers rom gets stuck and I can't switch to the next mode or turn off the GPS with it. What do you mean by "tapping the icon part of the tile", though? does the tile react differently to taps on the different parts of the tile?

Comment: And the delay, that I wrote about in the question, happens not with the original location tile from the rom, but with a tile that I created with QuickTask app, and which is controlled by tasker. This is of course understandable, because now two additional third party apps are used for this tile so some delays are expected depending on how many apps are running at the time that the tile is used. I have edited the question to make it more clear about which tile is used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95116/discussion-between-andy-yan-and-mnd).

Answer (score 0):

So an answer to my other similar [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213759/network-mode-switch-quick-settings-tile) helped me find a solution for this one as well.

It is possible to toggle the GPS with an app [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate).

I used the block, called "Location provider set state" from the "Location" category to enable/disable the GPS. And the block, called "Quick Settings tile show" from the "Interface" category to create and control the quick settings tile.

Here's a screenshot of the complete flow I'm using:

[image: Screenshot of an Automate flow for toggling the GPS]